# How can I write a code generator in Ceylon

Tags: code-generation, ceylon

I want to write a code generator that generates a class based on the meta model of another ceylon class. I want the code generator to run at compile time. What is the best way for me to do this. I could probably accomplish this by writing a plugin for gradle or the ceylon build system but I'm hoping for a simpler solution. Unfortunately, I don't see any support for code generators in ceylon. Also, are there any plans for code generators in ceylon?

I want to write this code generator because I'm thinking about writing a simple web framework for ceylon that look at a class like the following using the meta-model:
controller

```
shared class Controller() {
    shared void doSomething() => print("did it!");
}
```

I plan for it to be like Spring MVC. This framework would make a restful API from the Controller class that allows someone to write an AJAX call like this:

```
$http.get("/Controller/doSomething");
```

I want to make things more convenient, high level, and simple by doing something like GWT.  I want to create a code generator that automatically generates a class like this:

```
shared class RemoteController() {
    shared void doSomething() {
        $http.get("/Controller/doSomething");
    }
}
```

The RemoteController would be run in a user's browser as javaScript and allow client side ceylon code to do an Ajax call like this:

```
RemoteController().doSomething();
```

That would end up calling the Controller().doSomething() on the server so "did it!" would be printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AST Transformers](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-compiler/issues/1865) have been proposed, but are still in the early design phase. For now, to do compile-time code generation, you’ll have to rig up something of your own.

To actually generate the code, I would recommend use of [`ceylon.ast`](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.ast/) and [`ceylon.formatter`](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.formatter/). The workflow would roughly be:

1. analyze source code –

   - either parse it with `ceylon.ast` (`ceylon.ast.redhat::compileAnyCompilationUnit`) and analyze it without typechecking,
   - or parse it using the compiler, run the typechecker, then convert it to `ceylon.ast` (`ceylon.ast.redhat::anyCompilationUnitToCeylon`), keeping the typechecker information using the new [update hooks](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.ast/issues/87) in the very soon upcoming 1.2.0 release
2. edit the source code AST to add your new code (using a custom `ceylon.ast.core::Editor` that injects new class definitions into the `CompilationUnit`s), or perhaps create entirely new compilation units if the `RemoteController` lives in a different module
3. convert the `ceylon.ast` AST to a compiler AST and feed it into `ceylon.formatter` to turn the AST into code again (see [here](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.ast/blob/606e9388c2586c0cfb8affcc868c500564fb0a6d/source/test/ceylon/ast/samples/helloworld/testFormatted.ceylon#L31-L48) for an example of that)

Alternatively, if you integrate this into your build step, you could skip the `ceylon.formatter` part of step 3 and instead feed the converted compiler AST into the typechecker and rest of the compiler directly.

Comment: Ok. I'll do as you suggest and I'll make it part of my build. Once, ceylon gets code generators I'll switch to that. Thanks